# Mapping over nested array?

Tags: javascript

sorry for the noob question but I was wondering how I can map over an array with a number at the front of the array?

```
array = [
            ['geeks', '4', 'geeks' ],
            ['Hello', 'test', 'jeff'],
            ['Test', 'Pli', 'alphabet']
        ]
```

I am trying to loop over data which is outputted like this in my console

I need to loop over and display data of all arrays

Comment: This is not a valid array structure. Did you mean 
[
        [ 'geeks', '4', 'geeks' ],
        ['Hello', 'test', 'jeff],
        ['Test', 'Pli', 'alphabet']
]

Comment: @Shimi I think OP is just showing the indexes, although they skipped index `2` and went from `1` to `3`

Comment: Hi Shimi, yes i think so, if you take a look at my console array picture how come it shows the numbers to the left? I thought it was apart of the array

Comment: @Samathingamajig thanks, I just updated, but yes I think those just might be the index's from my console log.

Comment: The thing in the console is just a visual to show the index. It has nothing to do with the actual data in the array.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I need to loop over and display the data of all arrays

Comment: If you want a more _"code like"_ representation in your console, try `console.log(JSON.stringify(array, null, 2))`

Comment: You say loop over and display all data, but how do you plan to "display" the null values? Seems like you would need some logic in place to "format" this data beyond looping over?

Comment: so null values would return as nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the number next to the array in the DevTools in chrome is just there to tell you how many items are in the array.

it's not the actual array

if you want to edit the array or just access the elements there are multiple ways

### See this example:

```js
let someArray = [
[1,"a",2.3],
[2,"b",7.8],
[3,"c",4.5],
]

// if you want to change the items inside the array

//Array.map

someArray = someArray.map(innerArray =>{
  return innerArray.map(element => {
    //Do any thing to the element lets say that we want to convert all values to strings
    
    return String(element);
  })
})

console.log(someArray);

console.log('##################################');
//if you don't want to change the items inside the arreay you can:
// 1. remove the return statement from the Array.map function above

// 2. use any type of loop for, while loop

for(let i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++){
  for(let j = 0; j < someArray[i].length; j++){
      // Do any thing with the array item lets say you want to print it
      console.log(someArray[i][j]);
      
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks thats great, if I wanted to access certain elements in that entire array would i return something like 
return string(element[1]) to access the letter A B and C?

Comment: elem[0] will result in the full 1st array "[1,"a",2.3]"

if you want the 1st element you can access it by elem[0][0]

if you like this answer don't forget to upvote and accept this answer

Comment: Great, fantastic, thank you. If I wanted to access A B and C from all arrays not just from array 0 how can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

The following will print each string on the two-dimensional array

```
array.forEach((childArr) => childArr.forEach((str) => console.log(str)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your console show the index before each element content.

In your case, each element is also an array.

so, for mapping your specific array:

let newArray = array.map(innerArray => innerArray.map(element => { *your code* }));

Comment: This will create a new two-dimensional array without a specific requirment.

Comment: that's right. my point was to demonstrate how to change the content, not the structure.